# JWT Authentification with Asp.net core 2.1 works only on localhost

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, authorization, asp.net-core-2.1

I Added JWT Authentification to my existing aspnet core mvc web application to secure api for mobile app.

I used Multi auth and MultiPolicies for Authorization (Cookies with identity and JWT), I tested it on localhost using postman and the mobile app and it works fine. but when I deployed it to my remote server, I doesn't work. The authentification and the token generation works but when I access the api with a httpget request I get a rediriction to the mvc login page. 
My Startup.cs contains this :

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = identityDefaultOptions.CookieHttpOnly;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(identityDefaultOptions.CookieExpiration);
            options.LoginPath = identityDefaultOptions.LoginPath; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
            options.LogoutPath = identityDefaultOptions.LogoutPath; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
            options.AccessDeniedPath = identityDefaultOptions.AccessDeniedPath; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
            options.SlidingExpiration = identityDefaultOptions.SlidingExpiration;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingsOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = bool.Parse(jwtAppSettingsOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata)]);
        });
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));

        }).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver())
        .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings
            .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore).AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            // Add support for localizing strings in data annotations (e.g. validation messages) via the
            // IStringLocalizer abstractions.
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.AddAuthorization(options => 
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ApiUserPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("JwtRole", "ID"));

            });
```

[image: login-localhost]
This is a screenshot for login in localhost whith postman.
[image: login- production env]
This is the login using postman with production env.
[image: get - localhost]
Here's the request on localhost and it works, I got the json result. 
[image: get - production env]
And here I got this rediriction to mvc login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved by thamking some changes on **startup.cs** I *droped* the policies filter from **services.AddMVC** options definition and I added two authorization policies to Authorization definition like that :

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = identityDefaultOptions.CookieHttpOnly;
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(identityDefaultOptions.CookieExpiration);
            options.LoginPath = identityDefaultOptions.LoginPath; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
            options.LogoutPath = identityDefaultOptions.LogoutPath; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
            options.AccessDeniedPath = identityDefaultOptions.AccessDeniedPath; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
            options.SlidingExpiration = identityDefaultOptions.SlidingExpiration;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingsOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = bool.Parse(jwtAppSettingsOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.RequireHttpsMetadata)]);
        });
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            config.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        }).AddJsonOptions(opt =>
                opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver())
        .AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.SerializerSettings
            .ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore).AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            // Add support for localizing strings in data annotations (e.g. validation messages) via the
            // IStringLocalizer abstractions.
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
        services.AddAuthorization(options => 
        {
            options.AddPolicy(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .Build());

            options.AddPolicy("ApiUserPolicy", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .RequireClaim("JwtRole", "ID")
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .Build());
        });
```

To Understand how authorization more about policies and authentificationSchemas check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951994/6752288)